# pressure problem relating to basketball

Tags: pressure

I know that a basketball should have pressure between 7.5 to 8.5 pounds (51.71 kPa to 58.605 kPa) of pressure, according to NBA. However, the air pressure is less than 1 atm (101kPa). If the valve of the ball is open, why does the air leaks from the ball when the pressure inside the ball is less than the atmospheric pressure?

Answer (score 2):

The quoted pressures are what are called “gauge pressures” ie the pressure above atmospheric pressure which is around 15 pounds.

So a gauge pressure of 8 pounds corresponds to an absolute pressure of 8 + 15 = 25 pounds and so you would air to escape from the ball if the valve is opened.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure is higher inside the ball. When you say "7.5 to 8.5 pounds" you mean "7.5 to 8.5 pounds per squared inch (psi) higher from the atmosphere pressure.

In other word you take as reference the atmosphere pressure and add 7.5 to 8.5 psi.

The atmosphere pressure is around 14.5 psi which is around 1 bar. In my basketball club, we are used to say that a basket ball should be to 1.6 bar (around 23 psi) which correspond to your 14.5+8.5 psi.

Any way you couldn't have an a pressure less than 1 atmosphere in a ball (which is no rigid), if you remove gas (air) from the ball in order to down the pressure, the pressure will stay the same and the volume of inside the ball will reduce. (this is true for constant temperature, PV = nRT )

Comment: I wouldn't say it is common in Europe to reference the absolute pressure of something that is inflated. Pressures for bicycle tyres for example are commonly given as so called gauge pressure relative to the atmospheric pressure (and pumps with a pressure gauge certainly do not show the absolute pressure but the pressure relative to atmospheric pressure).